# Calculation error in calculating zeroes of complex cosine

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that the zeroes of $\cos z$ are $z=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$. But for some reason I am getting something weird here.

$$
\begin{align*}
\cos z =0 & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=0 
\\ & \Longleftrightarrow e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=0
\\ & \Longleftrightarrow e^{2iz}+1=0
\\ & \Longleftrightarrow e^{2iz}=-1 
\\ & \Longleftrightarrow e^{-2y}\cos 2x+i\,e^{-y} \sin 2x=-1 \text{ where } z=x+i\,y
\\ & \Longleftrightarrow e^{-2y}\cos 2x=-1 \text { and } e^{-2y} \sin 2x=0 
\\ & \Longleftrightarrow e^{-2y}\cos 2x=-1 \text { and } \sin 2x=0 \text{ as } e^{-2y} > 0 \text{ for } y \in \mathbb{R}
\\ & \Longleftrightarrow e^{-2y}\cos 2x=-1 \text{ and } 2x=2n \pi \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{Z}
\\ & \Longleftrightarrow e^{-2y}=1 \text{ and } x=n \pi \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ as } \cos 2n\pi=1 \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{Z}
\\ & \Longleftrightarrow y=0 \text{ and } x=n \pi \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{Z}
\\ & \Longleftrightarrow z=n \pi \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{Z} 
\end{align*}
$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $2x = 2\pi n$ seems to be it.

Answer (score 1):

From your 3rd statement
$$ e^{2iz} = -1 $$
$$ e^{2iz} = e^{i\pi}$$
$$ 2iz = i\pi +2 \pi n i$$
$$ z = \frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$$
Your seventh line doesn't hold, using your method $\sin 2x = 0$ so $2x = \pi n$, and solve.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of $\sin(2x)=0$ is not $x=n\pi$ but $x=n\tfrac{\pi}{2}$.